# Is a texture required to bound to be sampled?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I was under the impression if you set your sampler uniforms to the correct texture unit, it doesn't matter if the currently bound texture target is 0 or not.  For example,

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glGenTextures(1, &mytexture);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mytexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, my_data);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);    // This is the line I'm wondering about
```

Sometime later when drawing ...

```
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "mysampler"), 1);
//draw_stuff
```

Unfortunately, the screen is all black unless I keep GL_TEXTURE_2D bound to mytexture.  Is it illegal to sample when GL_TEXTURE_2D is bound to 0???

Comment: Yes, you must bind a texture (unless you're using the bindless texture extension).

Comment: Little tip: if your target version is 4.5 or your have support for `GL_ARB_direct_state_access`, consider using `glCreateTextures`, `glBindTextureUnit` and `glTextureParameter` instead of your bind to modify approach. Same effect, less calls and less risk of tampering with pipeline and object state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly, think about GL_TEXTUREN as a slot of several texture target types (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_3D etc). While activating GL_TEXTURE1 and binding a texture to GL_TEXTURE_2D you're telling the driver that 2d texture in slot 1 is going to be set to "mytexture".

Then you need to pass this information to your shader as well:

```
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "mysampler"), 1);
```

This simply tells your sampler2D in your shader that it should look for GL_TEXTURE_2D in slot 1. If you unbind the texture it will have nothing to sample from.